# React pass dom node as input to another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass wrapper Dom node to child component with reference. I tried below but it says its not a node.

```
const wrapperRef = React.createRef()
<Wrapper ref={wrapperRef}>
    <ChildComponent target={wrapperRef} />
<Wrapper>
```

I'm working with functional components. Any guidance on how to achieve it?

Comment: `<Wrapper>` is a React component, hence the reference is to a component and not a DOM node. You need to follow Anand's suggestion but use Forwarding Refs (https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) instead, because you want to access the DOM node of a component and not a DOM element in your JSX. Finally it seems a bit overkill if you ask me, in `<ChildComponent>` you can pass a ref to the outer DOM element and find it's parentNode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

Answer (score 0):

```
const wrapperRef = React.createRef()
<Wrapper ref={wrapperRef}>
    <ChildComponent target={wrapperRef.current} />
<Wrapper>
```

Just do **wrapperRef.current**

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried that as well following the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment you should use Forwarding Refs to get the DOM node of the `<Wrapper>` component. So it would look like this:

**Main File**

```
import React from "react";

import Wrapper from "./Wrapper";
import ChildComponent from "./ChildComponent";

function App() {
  const wrapperRef = React.createRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Wrapper ref={wrapperRef}>
        <ChildComponent target={wrapperRef} />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Wrapper.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Wrapper = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      <h3>Wrapper Component</h3>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
});

export default Wrapper;
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ChildComponent = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.target.current); // -> wrapper container outer <div>
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p className="lead">THIS IS THE CHILD COMPONENT</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

You can see a simple live example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-forward-ref-to-child-zwcd7

---

**Using Regular Refs in the ChildComponent**

As I mentioned in the comment if the structure of your JSX is simple as in the code I posted(that is the child component is a direct children of the outer wrapper of the parent component) you could also use `element.parentNode` in order to get the DOM node (main file doesn't change in this scenario):

**Wrapper.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Wrapper = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Wrapper Component</h3>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const ChildComponent = props => {
  let childOuterElement = null;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(childOuterElement.parentNode);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={e => (childOuterElement = e)}>
      <p className="lead">THIS IS THE CHILD COMPONENT</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildComponent;
```

Remember, this only works in that particular case, if `{props.children}` is placed somewhere else in the `<Wrapper>` component, you'll get a reference to that particular DOM node.